# Change Thunderbird's font sizes from the command line

Tags: linux, thunderbird

How can I change Thunderbird's font sizes from the command line?

In Firefox one can at least change an entry in the `user.js` file and restart it. Is there a similar way for Thunderbird?

Comment: Are you're looking to do this on-the-fly and for a single session, or to change the defaults?  If the latter, why do it from a command line instead of the normal configuration route?  Have you checked the command line options in the documentation?

Comment: I want to do this on the fly for a single session.

Comment: Yes I checked the documentation but didn't find any option.

Comment: It doesn't look like it.  The command line options appear pretty limited, and more oriented toward actions than settings, although there are a few session settings like window dimensions.  The main reference appears to be [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_Command_Line_Arguments), which contains links to several others: [1](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) and [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options).  Everything else I found pointed back to those links.